# MS Outlook 2016 auto-forward if body of email contains today or tomorrow's date

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I have Outlook 2016, and would like to set up auto-forward rule if the body of email contains today or tomorrow date.  So the date will change based on current date.  Is this something Outlook is capable of?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid not with build-in Outlook feature, the OOF message do not check the content of incoming message.

Comment: What the date to check is in email subject? Does that make any difference?